# Python type tuple cannot be converted MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, discord.py

I don't really understand how tuples work. But what i do know is that they look something like this.

```py
    (1, variable)
```

But I keep getting the error:

`Python type tuple cannot be converted`

Can someone help here is my code:

```
    @client.command()
async def buy(ctx, item: str):
    USER_ID = ctx.message.author.id
    write_log("Buy command requested")
    #write_log("Sending GET request to Cosmos API...")
    try:
        SQL.execute("SELECT price FROM shop WHERE itemname = %s", (item,))
        price = SQL.fetchone()
        SQL.execute("SELECT balance FROM Accounts WHERE user_id = %s", (USER_ID,))
        SQL.execute("UPDATE Accounts SET balance = balance - %s WHERE user_id = %s", (price, USER_ID))
        db.commit()
        await ctx.send(f"Successfully bought **{item}** for **{price} Rollars**.")
    except Exception as ex:
        write_log('ERROR')
        full_traceback = traceback.format_exc()
        write_log(f'Errored whilst sending ctx(embed), (about): {ex} {full_traceback}')
```

The FULL traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bot.py", line 316, in buy
    SQL.execute("UPDATE Accounts SET balance = balance - %s WHERE user_id = %s", (price, USER_ID))
  File "/home/vihanga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 248, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "/home/vihanga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 626, in prepare_for_mysql
    result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type tuple cannot be converted
```

Much appreciated if you could explain to me how it works and potentially help me solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetchone() function returns you the result as a tuple. So when you use fetchone the value stored in the price variable is a tuple like the following: `(100,)`.
Then when you execute your update query, you are passing this entire tuple as you received it inside another tuple. If for example, the price value was returned as `100`, then below is what your passing into the execute function.
`SQL.execute("UPDATE ..... ", ((100,), USER_ID))`

So the first element of your arguments is a tuple instead of a value, and you get that error because the database is thinking there is some value there that it can use, however since it finds a tuple instead as the first element you get that error.
What you should be doing is simply passing a single integer value as the price parameter so it looks something like: `SQL.execute("UPDATE ..... ", (100, USER_ID))`
To do this, you can either unpack the tuple by putting a * in front of it, or get the first value from it like `price[0]`.